# How to "show" user defined data type "sets" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, set, custom-data-type

if i've defined a set data type like:

```
data Set a = Set [a]
```

examples of sets:

- `empty = Set []`
- `s = Set [1,23]`

and i want to create an instance of show to display the set like this:
{1, 23} instead instead of [1,23]

how would i go about doing this?
so far i've tried something like:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Set a) where 
show (Set a) = "{" ++ show a ++ "}"
```

But this doesn't work because it gives me {[1,23]}

Is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: yep i know, just wondering if it can be done

Comment: Take a look at `Data.List.intercalate`.

Answer (score 2):

First: as you probably have it in your own code: type names and constructors must be uppercase.

```
data Set a = Set [a]
```

Second: the `Show` class isn't really meant for such pretty-printing. Often, users will expect its output to be valid Haskell code. `{1,2,3}` is not valid Haskell.

Anyway...

The easiest solution would be to just use the `Show` instance for the underlying list type, like you did, but trim away a leading `[` and trailing `]`:

```
trimOuterBrackets :: String -> String
trimOuterBrackets ('[':s)
                | (']':s') <- reverse s  = reverse s'
trimOuterBrackets s = s
```

Note however that this wouldn't work reliably, at least not for characters: `show $ Set ['b','l','a']` would yield `{"bla"}`, because strings are lists as well but [shown differently](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:showList).

Therefore, you should better define the function yourself. As bheklilr remarked, it can be done with [`intercalate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:intercalate): this takes a list of strings and another string that is used to “glue” those strings together. A list of strings can be obtained by [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map)ing the `show` function over the elements of your set...

This should be enough hints, I think.